# vim colorscheme poor syntax support

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have tried well over 15 different colorschemes for vim. I have made all of the correct settings for full color support in terminal. This 'problem' persists in both terminal and gvim. Perhaps it is not a bug and simply the design of the colorschemes themselves, but only one colorscheme I have tried actually has decent highlight support. For example:

In this python class all of the colorschemes will only highlight a couple of things.

- wombat only highlights comments and the `if`.

[image: vim-wombat theme]

- molokai is extremly dissapointing but at least gets the ints

[image: vim-molokai theme]

All of the themes I try are similar to these two except 'Crayon' which compares like so:

[image]

Most of the vim color-scheme github pages show previews with highlight support compared to crayon. My question is what might be causing this problem? or is this just the design of the themes themselves?

Comment: Colorschemes are very sensitive to their environment. How about showing us your actual config and telling us more about those context-free screenshots?

Comment: I would suggest using `zsh` as your shell, and using one of their great themes. This will improve how vim renders colors, as different terminal themes will render the same colors (green, blue, etc). differently across any terminal application.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax highlighting is the combination of two things:

- syntax definition, provided by syntax scripts typically found in `syntax/` or `after/syntax/`,
- highlighting definition, provided by colorschemes typically found in `colors/`.

The former defines syntax groups, the latter defines how those groups look.

But those almost never come in pairs so there's no guarantee whatsoever that every possible syntax group is properly handled by every possible colorscheme.

If a colorscheme you like doesn't handle some of the syntax groups you expect it to handle, open an issue or (better) patch it.